# How can I setting up redirect in web.config file with dynamic parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, web-config, sitecore

My url like this : https://myhospital.com/Hospitals-and-Clinics/Hospitals/Hospital-A/Our-Doctors

I try this script :

```
<location path="Our-Doctors">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.appointment.myhospital.com/" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

in the web config

But it does not works. It does not redirect to https://www.appointment.myhospital.com/

Hospital-A is name of hospital

So it can like this :

https://myhospital.com/Hospitals-and-Clinics/Hospitals/Hospital-B/Our-Doctors

or

https://myhospital.com/Hospitals-and-Clinics/Hospitals/Hospital-C/Our-Doctors

It's dynamic

How can I solve this problem?

Is using a regular expression for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Your config does not work because you are wrong path.
It must be

```
<location path="Hospitals-and-Clinics/Hospitals">
```

You can use URL Rewrite Module module in your case. like this:

```
<rule name="Demo" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="\/Our-Doctors$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?myhospital\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.appointment.myhospital.com/" />
</rule>
```

ref doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module